Flutter: Keep page's state alive in page switches
I am building a Flutter application with a bottom navigation bar where a click on an item in the bar triggers a route change.
One of these pages (let us call it 'Page A') is doing some HTTP calls to be build with quite some FutureBuilder's. But now, when I go to another page and then get back to Page A, it is entirely being rebuild as we would expect.
For this specific page/route I would actually like to NOT rebuild it in its entirity. Is there a builtin way to get to this behaviour?
I know I could do some coding myself to for example cache all responess and re-read them, but this is a code smell imo. The widgets inside should not have that responsability.
I took a look at the PageStorage widget, but this is only about scrolling where some specific widgets traverse up the widget tree to check if a parent is PageStorage. It is NOT a general approach in retaining an entire page on revisits.

Basically you can use the IndexedStack to build all the widgets at once and you can change between the selected widgets, those won't be recreated.
Result:

Code:
class NavigationBarSample extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavigationBarSample({super.key});

  @override
  State<NavigationBarSample> createState() => _NavigationBarSampleState();
}

class _NavigationBarSampleState extends State<NavigationBarSample> {
  int index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: IndexedStack(
          index: index,
          children: const [
            PageWidget(index: 0, color: Colors.red),
            PageWidget(index: 1, color: Colors.green),
            PageWidget(index: 2, color: Colors.blue),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: index,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              this.index = index;
            });
          },
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              label: 'Search',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              label: 'Settings',
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}

class PageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageWidget({
    required this.index,
    required this.color,
    super.key,
  });

  final int index;
  final Color color;

  @override
  State<PageWidget> createState() => _PageWidgetState();
}

class _PageWidgetState extends State<PageWidget> {
  int? value;

  void _loadData() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    setState(() {
      value = widget.index;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: widget.color,
      child: Center(
        child: value == null
            ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
            : Text(
                'Page ${widget.index}',
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 50,
                ),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Also if you want to create the page lazily (create the page when you click in the navigation item) , you can use any of these packages : https://pub.dev/packages?q=IndexedStack+lazy

This could indeed be a solution but I must admit I am not a big fan of it. It jsut stacks widget above each other to pretend to be a new route instead of having an acutal new route without rebuilding the widget inside. If for example page with index 1 had Colors.green.withAlpha(100); as background color it would show different depending on the page you got to before it.

You can set full screen widgets as children, that's not an issue
